# How to convert minified to unminified JavaScript by mapping with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify, unminify

i have got a lot of way to beautify javascript code. but all of those way of conversions are based on without mapping variable. let see with example of minified js:

```
!function(a){var b=[],c={init:function(){a(document).ready(c.ready);a(window).on("load",c.load)},ready:function(){},load:function(){setTimeout(function(){console.log(this)},1000)},};c.init()}(jQuery)
```

now i am looking for a automated tools/system to convert the minified js code to a beautified code where i can map all minified variables (a,b,c ..) to meaningful variables like ($,var1,var2 ...) where i can able to assign mapping of variable like a=$, b=var1, c=var3 and so on. So that i can get a beautified code like

```
! function($) {

    var var1 = [];

    var var2 = {
        init: function() {

             $(document).ready(var2.ready);
             $(window).on("load", var2.load);
        },
        ready: function() {

        },
        load: function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(this);
            }, 1000)
        },
    };

    var2.init();

}(jQuery);
```

What are the best tools to perform such conversion?

Comment: `var1`, `var2` and `var3` are no more meaningful than `a`, `b` and `c`. If you really want meaningful variable names, the only way is for a human to understand the code and rename the variables, since computers can't do it yet.

Comment: i know var1,var2.. are not realstic. but i need a way map variables like a = var1, b= var2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the list of online tools that will help you  to beautify javascript code. but you will not get the feature to map variables
- https://www.cleancss.com/javascript-beautify/
- https://codebeautify.org/jsviewer
- https://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-beautifier.html
- https://beautifier.io/
- https://www.prettifyjs.net/
- https://jstherightway.org/
- https://prettier.io/playground/
- https://html-cleaner.com/js/